# Image blinks when page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have some simple jQuery functions running to let an image fade in, but before fading in I hide the image, when the page is reloaded the image blinks and then fades in, because the image is on the html page. Is there a way to fix that blink?

Answer (score 4):

It is better to add some code, for perfect solution, but as it stays, my answer works. Just *assuming*, you are not hiding the image or JavaScript is loading slowly. So, do this. Give `style="display: none;"` so that the image doesn't get loaded in the view:

```
<img style="display: none;" />
```

And after jQuery is loaded, you can use:

```
$("img").fadeIn(); // Or whatever!
```